# Fast processing of numpy polyfit on 3d arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, linear-regression

I have two numpy arrays with shapes of (400, 1000, 1000).
I want to apply numpy.polyfit using the two arrays as input and fitting over axis 0. I have tried the following code, which could be very slow if I want to fit larger arrays.

`rows = arr1.shape[1]
 cols = arr1.shape[2]
 for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        idx = np.isfinite(arr1[:, i, j]) & np.isfinite(arr2[:, i, j])
        # Get slope
        slope = np.polyfit(arr1[:, i, j][idx], arr2[:, i, j][idx], 1)[0]
        ...`

Any idea how to speed this up?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**Linear Regression**

Regarding your code example i assume that you only wan't to make a simple linear regression, where you need the slope of the linear function.

This is a much simpler problem than a general polyfit. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression

Your example take about **170s** on my PC. I wan't to show two versions (only numpy which gives 45s and a solution using numba which lasts 2.5s on my machine (Core i7-4771).

**Using only numpy (45s without Test-array creation)**

```
#Creating the Test Arrays
import numpy as np
import time

arr1=np.random.rand(400, 1000, 1000)
arr2=np.random.rand(400, 1000, 1000)

#Test function
def Test(arr1,arr2):
  Slope=np.empty((arr1.shape[1],arr1.shape[2]))
  for i in range(arr1.shape[1]):
    for j in range(arr1.shape[2]):
      idx = np.isfinite(arr1[:, i, j]) & np.isfinite(arr2[:, i, j])
      # Get slope
      Slope[i,j]=lin_regression(arr1[idx, i, j],arr2[idx, i, j])

#Linear regression
def lin_regression(arr1,arr2):
  m_x=np.mean(arr1)
  m_y=np.mean(arr2)

  slope=np.sum((arr1-m_x)*(arr2-m_y))/np.sum((arr1-m_x)**2)
  return slope
```

**Using numba (2.5s)**

```
#Creating the Test Arrays
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
import time

arr1=np.random.rand(400, 1000, 1000)
arr2=np.random.rand(400, 1000, 1000)

@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def lin_regression(arr1,arr2,slope):
  m_x=np.mean(arr1)
  m_y=np.mean(arr2)

  slope=np.sum((arr1-m_x)*(arr2-m_y))/np.sum((arr1-m_x)**2)

@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)
def Test(arr1,arr2):
  Slope=np.empty((arr1.shape[1],arr1.shape[2]))
  for i in nb.prange(arr1.shape[1]):
    for j in range(arr1.shape[2]):
      idx = np.isfinite(arr1[:, i, j]) & np.isfinite(arr2[:, i, j])
      # Get slope
      Slope[i,j]=lin_regression(arr1[idx, i, j],arr2[idx, i, j])
```